# Mule: Do I need a DevKit?

Tags: mule, anypoint-studio

I have a scenario in which I have to isolate every inbound HTTP Connection and store it in a hash storage (like a Hashtable) along withe username & other connection information.

How do I isolate this HTTP connection in a mule flow? I think I might need to install DevKit? That way I could use annotations based java classes and get a handle on the connection.

Or is that an overkill? Because firstly I don't see the devkit tab in my studio. Is there an alternate way of achieving the same?

Answer (score 0):

I did not get the part of isolating the HTTP Connections though , but if you wish to use **Devkit** you first need to install it in your AnypointStudio

Go into **Help >Install New Software >Select Devkit Update Site**

If you do not have the **Devkit Update Site** in your studio do use this **[link](http://studio.mulesoft.org/r5/devkit)**.